# How to Improve Developer Experience When Integrating Blazor Components Custom Elements into ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-component, blazor-webassembly, custom-element

I'm currently working on a legacy ASP.NET MVC application, and my goal is to integrate Blazor components that are compiled to custom elements within this ASP.NET MVC app.

I came across this article: [Blazor Custom Elements with React](https://dvoituron.com/2022/12/22/blazor-custom-elements-react/) and several others like it which detail the steps to achieve this integration.

The process described involves:

- Publishing the Blazor app.
- Copying the published files to the ASP.NET MVC application.

While I've been able to make it work, the developer experience (DevX) is less than optimal. This approach results in an extended feedback cycle due to the need to constantly publish and transfer files. Additionally, since I'm working with published artifacts, debugging becomes notably difficult.

Here are my concerns:

- Is this the current best practice for integrating Blazor components into an ASP.NET MVC application?
- Are there any alternatives that provide a quicker feedback loop for this purpose?
- Has the Blazor team mentioned any plans or upcoming features to enhance the developer experience for such use cases?

Any guidance or alternative methods to improve the development workflow for this scenario would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!